# Get unique random numbers from 1-40

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to get unique random numbers each time from nos 1-40 without using an array.Is there any optimised way to get this in action script 3.

Comment: This is not related to max min random no.I am talking about unique random.

Comment: ex: if i got random no 2 then this no "2" should not be repeated again

Comment: why not use an array ? is this a school question ? ... also it has nothing to do with AS3, same principles apply to any programming language.. this is just about your logic.

Comment: I am making a game for mobile devices which have less memory that's why i dint want to use an array.
No this is not a school level question.

Comment: i got 1 down vote because somebody misunderstood this question with max min random no. and dont know about other

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu can you please provide me the logic

Comment: @Kaif The other downvote was from me, the reason is lack of own research. Actually, using arrays does not eat up too much memory, you can save for a thousand arrays by dropping a single extra `BitmapData` instance.

Comment: Honestly, an array with 40 elements is not going to use so much memory on mobile devices. If you want to read more about optimizing performance I suggest starting here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/flashplatform_optimizing_content.pdf

Comment: @CristinaGeorgescu ok but can't we use string instead of array?

Comment: If you use string instead of array, you would have to convert from Number to String. You could use a Dictionary with keys from 1 to 40 and then generate random numbers between 1-40. For each random number, you check if there is a value associated in the Dictionary with the random number key. If there is, you discard the current number. If there isn't, you keep that random number and set the value in the dictionary to true (noDict[currentRandom] = true). You should also keep track of the number of times you set a value in the dictionary, so you know when to stop. It's a bit contrieved though.

Comment: @Kaif Why are you making this so hard for yourself? An array can be as large or as small as you need and any overhead is so small it's not worth thinking about. If you need 40 numbers then an array of 40 numbers will be the size of (size of number) * 40, You literally will not find a better solution for storing a sequence of numbers.
Just fill an array with the numbers 1-40 and find/create a method to shuffle/randomize the order.

Comment: USE A FREEKING ARRAY! it is faster and lighter as any other dumb string solutions. Why you want to have a different thing than an normal working one. I also build mobile apps and to be honest i am more worried about list renderes and UI performance as for parsing an 40 items array...

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to use permutation, as you have to record those numbers you've already generated. And using these numbers require a set of some kind, aka `Array`. It's possible to solve this issue by using other data types, but they will essentially narrow down to an array of some sort.

A simple permutation code looks like this:

```
class Permutation {
    private var _a:Array; // or Vector.<int> if you like
    private var n:int; // next element
    public function Permutation() {
        reset(1);
    }
    public function reset(size:int=100):void {
        _a.length=0;
        for (n=0;n<size;n++) _a.push(n);
        for (n=0;n<size;n++) {
            var x:int=Math.floor(size*Math.random());
            if (x==n) continue;
            var swap:int=_a[x];
            _a[x]=_a[n];
            _a[n]=swap;
        }
        n=0;
    }
    public function getNext():int {
        if (n==_a.length) return -1; // or any error value
        n++;
        return _a[n-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: That is barely an answer.

Comment: If "barely" then it's sone kind of an answer. Try improving it, if you can. Yours isn't a quality answer too.

Comment: @BotMaster Okay, I have added some code too. Note the low complexity and encapsulation.

Answer (score -1):

No array.

```
var generatedNumberCount:int;
var generatedNumberRef:Object = {};

for(var i:int = 0; i < 150; i++)
{
    var result:Number = generateRandomInt(50);
    trace(result);
}
trace(generatedNumberCount)
function generateRandomInt(limit:int):Number
{
    if(generatedNumberCount >= limit)
    {
        return NaN;
    }
    var output:int = Math.ceil(Math.random() * limit);  
    while(generatedNumberRef[output] != undefined)
    {
        output = Math.ceil(Math.random() * limit);
    }
    generatedNumberRef[output] = true;
    generatedNumberCount++;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: You use a fake array made from an `Object`. So what?

Comment: It's a hash table so I don't have to loop, it's not a fake array at all. In what is it a fake array?

Comment: wow! you vote me down for actually giving a usable real answer ... Very sad indeed ....

Comment: I didn't vote you down. Also, imagine you have a faulty RNG, and you have to generate 40 numbers out of 40. This code can potentially hang, because a faulty RNG might not give results correspondig to a certain number for a very long time.

Comment: Then you are affirming without even testing the code itself. Once all number within the limit are generated it will return NaN. Anyway I show some code, what do you show?

Comment: In theory it could take 1 million years for one specific number to be generated in a 0-40 range. In reality they are all very likely to appear at least once out of 10000 tries or less.

Comment: @BotMaster You use a fake array. Bad, poor coding: voted down!